# sum/group days by week and year

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The following is a simplified version of my problem.

I got a table in which I list whether an employee was working on that specific project or not. So the columns are calendar-week, date, day-of-week, name and the rows are the current week, the date, the day and a simple 1 if that employee was working or not.

```
A   B           C     D           F
CW  Date        Day   Employee1   Employee2
31  01.08.18    Wed   1           
31  02.08.18    Thu   1           1
```

Now I wanna assemble a second table that gives me the numbers per week:

```
A   B       C           D
CW  Year    Employee1   Employee2
31  2018    2           1
```

I tried using `SUMIF` or `COUNTIF` but can't get it working. Here's an example for Employee1:

> =COUNTIF(Table1!D:D; AND(YEAR(Table1!B:B)=Table2!B; Table1!A:A=Table2!A)

So, it should sum/count the occurrences of 1 in column D (employee 1) if the year is 2018 and the calendar week is 31. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a pivot table

Comment: Gosh, good idea. Got it! Nevertheless, would be interesting to know how to solve it with COUNTIF.

Comment: Use COUNTIFS and use greater than or equal to  1st of Jan less than or equal to 31st of Dec of that year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming you have data in Range 
  `A3:G6`.
- Fill **CW** `31` & `32` in `A11` and 
  `A12`.

**Note,** you may use `WEEKNUM` Formula to get **CW**.

- Get **Year** in `B11` you may write 
  this Formula:
  `=Year($B$3)` and fill down.
- Write this Formula in `C11`, fill right 
  then down.

`=SUMIFS(D$3:D$6,$A$3:$A$6,"="&ROW(A31))`

**N.B.**

- `ROW(A31)` in formula returns `31` which 
  is **CW** to match in column `A`.
- And it becomes `32` as soon formula fills 
  down.
- Format for DATE in Col B is `DD/MM/YY`.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Matthias ,,, keep asking ☺